# The server stopped the handshake (Mono)

Tags: c#, ssl, unity-game-engine, mono, webclient

I'm using the Unity and C#. Trying to download file from SSL protected website with  Using System.Net. However I'm getting following error log

> I/Unity   (11583): System.Net.WebException: Error getting response stream (Write: The authentication or decryption has failed.): SendFailure ---> System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: The server stopped the handshake.
>   I/Unity   (11583):   at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.SafeReceiveRecord (System.IO.Stream s) [0x00000] in :0
>   I/Unity   (11583):   at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.OnNegotiateHandshakeCallback (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in :0
>   I/Unity   (11583):   at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.AsyncHandshakeCallback (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in :0
>   I/Unity   (11583):   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   I/Unity   (11583):   at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.AsyncHandshakeCallback (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in :0
>   I/Unity   (11583):   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   I/Unity   (11583):   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in :0

After the research I found similar issue, but it was just the SSL security check, which I'm already overriding and just returning the true. My issue is different, server stops the handshake. After trying out different websites, I found out that it works on some.

It works for:

- https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.79/blender-2.79b-windows64.msi

It doesn't work for:

- https://hagrid.me/obb.zip
- https://hagrid.me/obb.obb
- https://playfab.com
- Etc.

My code:

```
public void DownloadFile()
{
    cancelled = false;

    client = new WebClient();

    client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(downloadUrl), GooglePlayDownloader.GetExpansionFilePath() + "/" + newFileName);


    downloading = true;
    client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
    client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(DownloadFileCompleted);
}
```

Comment: Although I too get an exception, the message I get is "An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream."

Comment: @John It could be temporary, I was editing my SSL on my server just now.

Comment: @John Tried it just now, getting same error log (I mean, what I mentioned in the thread, not one like yours). I wonder if there is something wrong with SSL cert itself..

Comment: I'm not exactly sure of the issue, but it _may_ be something to do with TLS versions. I'm trying to check.

Comment: @John That's what I thought at first, however after checking out, blender and hagrid uses same Let's Encrypt's SSL cert, both TLS1.2 It works on one, and doesn't work on another..As for the playfab, they are using the Amazon issued cert seems like

Comment: It looks like playfab supports TLS1.0 still (according to ssllabs), so I'm out of ideas, to be honest.

Comment: @John Actually, playfab downloads from different server. Hold on

Comment: @John
So once the signed URL is requested, it seems like it actually directs to pf-content-live.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com

Can you run the check on amazonaws.com?

Comment: The full pf-content subdomain's SSL [supports TLS1.0](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=pf-content-live.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com), so that seems to be OK.

Comment: Uh.. Have no idea what else I could try.